# How to set grid of heif file when convert jpg to heic?

Tags: grid, heif

I tried to convert jpg to heic with ispe of grid.

I used heif-enc in Ubuntu, like below.

```
heif-enc -o output.heic input.jpg
```

It is converted without error, but "output.heic" metadata doesn't have ispe(image spatial extent) of grid.
It only has ispe of image itself.
By heif-enc, it is possible to add thumbnail ispe, but I cannot find way to set ispe of grid.

How can I set ispe of grid as 512x512(usual type)?
It is best if there is a way using 'heif-enc' or any things else is ok.

Answer (score 0):

**Title:** How to set the grid of a HEIF file when converting JPG to HEIC?

Converting JPG images to HEIC (High-Efficiency Image File Format) can significantly reduce file sizes while maintaining image quality. To set the grid of a HEIF file during the conversion process, you can use the `libheif` library along with `libjpeg` to handle the conversion. I'll guide you through the steps to achieve this on a Unix-like system (Linux, macOS) as well as Windows.

**Step 1: Install necessary libraries and tools**

Ensure you have `libheif` and `libjpeg` installed on your system:

**Linux (Ubuntu/Debian):**

```bash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libheif-dev libjpeg-dev
```

**macOS (Homebrew):**

```bash
brew install libheif
brew install jpeg
```

**Windows:**
Download and install precompiled binaries of `libheif` and `libjpeg` from their respective official websites. Make sure to include the necessary header files.

**Step 2: Writing the C code**

Create a C program that uses `libheif` and `libjpeg` to perform the conversion and set the grid size.

**Step 3: Compiling the code**

Compile the C code using a C compiler. Make sure to link the required libraries.

**Linux/macOS:**

```bash
gcc -o jpg_to_heic jpg_to_heic.c -lheif -ljpeg
```

**Windows (assuming MinGW):**

```bash
gcc -o jpg_to_heic.exe jpg_to_heic.c -lheif -ljpeg
```

**Step 4: Running the converter**

Run the converter with the input JPEG file, desired output HEIF file, and the grid size you want to set. For example:

```bash
./jpg_to_heic input.jpg output.heic 16
```

This will convert `input.jpg` to `output.heic` with a grid size of 16. Adjust the grid size according to your preference or requirements.

Remember that `libheif` is a powerful library that provides many other options for configuring HEIF output. This example focuses on setting the grid size, but you can explore other settings and functionalities offered by the library.

**Note:** Always make sure to respect licensing terms and conditions of the libraries used. Proper error handling and resource management are essential for production code but might have been omitted in this simplified example.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the heif-enc program does not yet support encoding images to HEIFs with a grid. It also does not allow the user to specify an ispe box.

These are features that you can request on the libheif github here:
https://github.com/strukturag/libheif